# google protobuf - how to access size of buffer as specified in .proto file?

Tags: c, protobuf-c, nanopb

My protobuf file is

```
message Msg{
    // User Authentication data as bytes. 
    bytes MsgData = 1 [(nanopb).max_size = 2048];
}
```

When I generate the **C** API, the relevant parts are:

```
#define PB_BYTES_ARRAY_T(n) struct { pb_size_t size; pb_byte_t bytes[n]; }

/* Struct definitions */
typedef PB_BYTES_ARRAY_T(2048) Msg_AuthenticationData_t;

/* Maximum encoded size of messages (where known) */
#define Msg_size  2051
```

**QUESTION - 1**

The size of the buffer, is `2048`; how do I access that value using the API?

I know I can do `sizeof(Msg_AuthenticationData_t.bytes)` because it's set at `2048` at compile time but seems like there should be an API.

**QUESTION - 2**
And what is with the `2051`? How is that usable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sizeof(Msg_AuthenticationData_t.bytes)` is the API to get the size of the array. That's the way it works for any C type.

The encoded message size is the maximum size of the output of `pb_encode()`. Because of the field type and length headers in [protobuf encoding](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding), it can be a few bytes larger than the payload.

Comment: Then what's the point of the `#define Msg_size  2051`? Where can I as a user of the API use it?

Comment: @Bob For example in allocating buffers for the encoded message data.